# If I buy an RTX card just to render will it work?

Tags: rendering

I have a quadro card connected to my screen, but I want to have the RTX 2080 do the rendering as the selected compute device - if it is not plugged into the monitor will this still work? (basically can the rtx send a picture of what its doing via the quadro display output for Evee?)

Comment: It wil work for Cycles rendering, I doubt it will work with EEVEE

Comment: Cool that's all I wanted it to do! Just for F12 while I keep on modelling - thanks for the answer.